# When the sun's magnetic field reverses, how can "the north pole (have) already (...) reversed, and (we are) waiting for the south pole to catch-up"?

Tags: astrophysics, solar-system, popular-science, magnetic-fields, magnetic-monopoles

I was reading a popular news account of the sun's upcoming magnetic field reversal at http://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2013/0807/Sun-s-magnetic-reversal-means-big-changes-for-the-solar-system-video, and was confused already in the second paragraph:

> Data from NASA-supported observatories indicate that the next flip will happen in just three to four months – the north pole has already jumped the gun and reversed, and scientists are now just waiting for the south pole to catch-up. The completed flip will herald changes throughout the entire solar system, according to a NASA video.

This doesn't make any sense to me.  Given that [there are no magnetic monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole), there is no way for the sun to have two "south" magnetic poles.  The field lines have to close somehow.  (Granted, I don't for the life of me understand what a [flux rope](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sdo/news/flux-ropes.html) is, although the videos are cool.)  I conclude that one of the following must be true:

1. Most likely: the reporter misinterpreted / mistranslated-into-colloquial something a scientist said.
2. Reasonably likely: my understanding of magnetism is completely wrong.
3. Unlikely: all of the known physics of magnetism is completely wrong.

The reason I think 3. is unlikely is that it would have been the headline, not "Sun's magnetic reversal..."

So which is it?  More generally, if it's possible to give a somewhat-technical description of "Sun's magnetic reversal", that would be awesome (but I realize that most likely that would require a book chapter, and is outside the scope of this forum).  Feel free to gear your answer at the level of an incoming physics PhD student.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. I've deleted some material from the question that was chatty or apologetic -- this kind of thing is discouraged on SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The news [release from NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/the-suns-magnetic-field-is-about-to-flip/) does mention this. Apparently in this transitional phase the field is not well represented as a dipolar field. Right now it may be a Quadra polar or higher (even numbered) field. Think of the total field being the superposition of multiple non-axial non-centered dipoles. The field is weakening in intensity too and may become weaker still before it strengthens into a reversed dipole field.

Comment: +1 I would only add the (nearly trivial) observation that a more chaotic field need not be symmetric in any way - there can be a strongly concentrated inward flux in one part of the surface with all the outward flux being rather diffuse on a bigger patch, just so long as the surface integral of the normal component is 0.